# How to get data from array each table to object javascrit

Tags: javascript

```
$(".removeButton").click(function () {
  var Cart = {};
            
   $('#CartReqUpdateProduct tbody tr').each(function (index, item) {
    var item = $(this).closest("tr");
    Cart = {
    proid: item.find('td').eq(1).find('input').val(),
        
        }   
  });
  console.log("this is your id"+Cart);
});
```

This is result = this is your id[object Object]

This is expecting = this is your id 67

Comment: Hi Mango, can you please try to find out what's inside Cart? You may try console.log(Cart)

Comment: console.log(Cart) is show data like array object but I don't want to console like this I want to console.log get data from array to object

Comment: Yes, It is expected that it will show as object. Can you show me the output? A screenshot would be best.

Comment: when I print this console have output like this ( this is your id[object Object] ) but my expected that output like this ( this is your id 67 )

Comment: I just want to return data from array to object by filter from each table array

Comment: Try this ->console.log("this is your id"+Cart.proid)

Comment: `Cart` _is_ an `Object`, and when you `console.log` an `Object`, you'll see exactly that. To see its values, you'd need to log a _property of the object_, not the object itself. (e.g. `console.log(Cart.proid)` rather than `console.log(Cart)`. Also, by convention, avoid the capital letter at the beginning of a variable name, unless when creating a `Class` object.

Comment: Why nobody mentions using a simple `console.log("this is your id", Cart)`? console.log can take multiple arguments!

Comment: console.log("this is your id", Cart) is return String with object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `console.log("this is your id"+Cart.proid)`